# Running Plink in a Windows Batch - Issues

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, putty, plink

I'm putting together a very basic automation script using the windows batch operation in which will loop through a list of IP addresses and run a plink command to logon and keep alive the account on the server because it has recently logged onto the server.

I believe I have most of the function working however I am having an issue with passing through the password. I'm seeing an issue where if the password I have has special characters and in which I run the script through command prompt it does not pass through the special character to the  plink command. Here is a look of the script:

```
@echo on

SET userid=root
SET passwd=Welcome1%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "ipaddress.txt" ') do (
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
plink.exe -pw %passwd% %userid%@%%i hostname
popd
)
```

The ipaddress.txt file contains:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

The idea is to go through the list for each IP address, logon and validate access. I'm also looking to ensure the value Y or N is passed to make sure a server is trusted or not as part of the script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is that *"special character"*?

Comment: Percent signs have to be doubled. `set "passwd=Welcome*%%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see your script behaviour with `@echo on` (run it from within a `cmd` window instead of double-clicking). You are right that [some *special characters* need to be escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). If your password should be `Welcome1%` literally then use

```
SET passwd=Welcome1%%
```

or advanced `set` command syntax

```
SET "passwd=Welcome1%%"
```

**Edit**. Above advice covers particularly `%` percentage sign in a string. However, escaping some characters with *special meaning* (e.g. [redirectors](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `<`, `>`, `|`, `&` etc.) as `^<`, `^>`, `^|`, `^&` seems to be a bit inconvenient and could not suffice. Therefore required advanced `set` command syntax *and* [delayed expansion enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) instead.

For instance, `Wel<come>1%` string could be used as follows:

```
SET "userid=root"
SET "passwd=Wel<come>1%%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "ipaddress.txt" ') do (
  pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    plink.exe -pw !passwd! %userid%@%%i hostname
  ENDLOCAL
  popd
)
```

Comment: Thank You worked as expected. I'm assuming the details given are in reference to delayed expansions?